# Passing multiple arguments to scipy stats functions in python

Tags: python

I am trying to pass multiple arguments to some scipy stats functions in python eg. stats.kruskal but the problem is sometimes I got only three arguments sometimes i got many more and I do not know how to pass it dynamically. Here is what I got so far:

```
dependent_variable = dataset[attributes[0]]
independent_variable = dataset[attributes[1]]
dependent_variable_values = dataset[attributes[0]].unique()
i = 0
stre = ''
temp = []
for item in dependent_variable_values:
    temp.append(dataset.loc[dataset[attributes[0]] == dependent_variable_values[i]])
    i += 1
for i in range(i):
    stre = temp[i]['Oceny']
    i = i - 1
```

My first idea was to create string with these arrays but it does not work that way.

Here is example of the same code but less automatic which works fine but as I said before I will not get always only three arguments and know data so well. I want this code below more automatic to work with every data.

```
a = dataset['Group']
b = dataset['Mark']

c = dataset.loc[dataset['Group'] == '1'] #here I know that group contains only 3 possibly values 1, 2, 3 but I will know that in every case
d = dataset.loc[dataset['Group'] == '2']
e = dataset.loc[dataset['Group'] == '3']
testy = [c['Mark'], d['Mark'], e['Mark']] #marks for group 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: What scipy function? I don't see you making single call other than to `Series.unique()` and `list.append()`. And generally we pass a variable number of arguments using `func(*args)` or `func(*position_args, **keyword_args)`.

Comment: Yeah It works thank you very much!
kruskal-wallis function or rho-spearman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `func(*args)` or `func(*position_args, **keyword_args)`

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-pass-optional-or-keyword-parameters-from-one-function-to-another